# Conversion of HTML into HAML : " raw" tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml, all-in-one-event-calendar

I'm very new to haml . I'm able to convert some of the basic html to haml 
but I coudn't find any answer for the following 
how to convert `<%= raw(event_calendar) %>` in haml ..
and also say the website where i can learn haml completely

Comment: http://html2haml.heroku.com/

Comment: Thank you .. Awesome Link .. I can learn easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing much to learn in haml. Below is an eg. It is self explanatory. Some thing to note is that there are no end/closing tags, indentation is used instead

erb:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <span class='myArticle' data-article-id='<%= article.id %>'>
    <%= article.name %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

haml:

```
- @articles.each do |article|
  %span.myArticle{"data-article-id" => article.id}
    = article.name
```